# Android YouTube SDK - video not playing in some android devices

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I launched a native android app where I used [YouTube SDK](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player) to play youtube videos.

Everything was going well for months. But since yesterday the app can't play videos in some devices. There aren't specific patterns that can be seen in the reported devices or the operating systems. So far, I've got reports that this issue occurred in **some** Xiaomi and Vivo models running on android 10, 11, 12.

How do I pinpoint the exact issue that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing cache of the youtube app solved my problem.

Also, PierfrancescoSoffritti's [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) library does not have issues like this. This library is 100% compliant with youtube's terms and I think it is better than YouTube's SDK except for the fact that you might need to write more codes to customize it to your requirements.

**PS:** This issue was probably related to youtube app's update on first week of June, 2022. After they published another update later that week, this issue was automatically resolved (the sudden spike in crash report returned to normal even though we did not publish any update). But we switched to PierfrancescoSoffritti's youtube player anyways.